# Can anyone recommend an open-source up-to-date actively developed basic AR library for iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, augmented-reality

The issue I'm having is I can't find an actively developed open-source AR library for iOS.

I don't need 3D support or maker based recognition. Just the ability to place icons/labels like Yelp's famous monocle feature.

My goal is to integrate AR into my app so that users can view POI's near their location. My app already has a map view doing this and I thought it would be cool to use an AR view too.

I've looked at:

- Mixare (iOS version not very smooth, is buggy, and code is chaotic. Also does not seem to be supported anymore, there's not been an update for 5 months).
- ARKit (not been updated in 4 years and has a warning about it being a bit rough).

Anyone had an experience or know of a good all round library that I can drop into my application?

Alternatively if anyone can recommend any books or tutorials on how to write your own that would be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/ios

Comment: @borrrden Seems to do a lot of stuff I don't need i.e. maker recognition or 3D. Do you know if it's capable of doing simpler offline AR with just place labels?

Comment: @borrrden After reading the documentation it seems `Vuforia` does not support GPS and is designed only to support marker recognition. So it does not fit my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple integration you can use the [Junaio plugin](http://www.metaio.com/products/junaio-plugin/) or the [Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/get-started/ios). They are not open-source solution but sufficient if you are not interested to modify the layout, representation or internal computation for transforming POIs into an AR view.

There is an example for GPS-based AR from the Professional iOS programming Book available from github, as well as PanicAR (just search on github.com).

Finally Apples provides a basic implementation in the iOS developer library: look for pARK.